# Project deployment on remote via Cargo maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, servlets, deployment, cargo

I'm trying to deploy a servlet project using `cargo` plugin.

pom.xml file:

```
...
<!-- cargo plugin  -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <container>
                <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                <type>remote</type>
                <systemProperties>
                    <cargo.jvmargs>-XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx1024m</cargo.jvmargs>
                </systemProperties>
            </container>
            <configuration>
                <type>runtime</type>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.hostname>example.com</cargo.hostname>
                    <cargo.protocol>http</cargo.protocol>
                    <cargo.servlet.port></cargo.servlet.port>
                    <cargo.remote.username>verticals-renderer</cargo.remote.username>
                    <cargo.remote.password>verticals-renderer</cargo.remote.password>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>com.foo.foo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>foo-renderer</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <properties>
                            <context>latest</context>
                        </properties>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>

        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <!-- End cargo plugin -->
...
```

As you see I want to deploy the project on a remote `domain` e.g; `example.com` but when I run `mvn cargo:doploy` I get:

```
Connection timed out
```

That's because it tries to deploy the project to:

```
http://example.com:/manager
```

Any idea how can I remove the colon (`:`) from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove cargo.servlet.port from your configuration properties? I believe the empty port in your URL will then disappear.

Comment: you can try to use the default 80 port.